# Is it possible to have sub query filter in JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I tried to execute following SQL in MS Access.

Basically `TAB3` use as a translate table

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1 T1 INNER JOIN TAB2 T2
ON T1.MemNo = T2.MemID
AND (T1.SID = (SELECT x.Col1 FROM TAB3 x WHERE x.Col2 =  T2.SVID))
```

But it gives me a syntax error

What could be the possible issue

updated:

```
TAB1

MemNo   SID

116537  S110
116537  D011
575788  D012
214438  S110
434675  D114
214438  D011
208368  D012
208368  S110

TAB2

MemID   SVID

116537  110
116537  11
214438  11
434675  114
214438  110
575788  12
208368  12
208368  110


TAB3

Col1    Col2

D011    11
S110    110
D114    114
D012    12
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the syntax error specify any information - an error number etc? Perhaps one of the number columns is text not a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not move the subquery to the WHERE statement of your query?

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1 T1 
INNER JOIN TAB2 T2 ON T1.MemNo = T2.MemID
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM TAB3 x 
               WHERE x.Col2 =  T2.SVID
               AND x.Col1 = T1.SID )
```

Try the following with LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1 T1 
LEFT JOIN TAB2 T2 ON T1.MemNo = T2.MemID
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM TAB3 x 
               WHERE x.Col2 =  COALESCE(T2.SVID, x.Col2)
               AND x.Col1 = T1.SID )
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Above solution execute without syntax error, no results though.

Comment: @Manthree Peiris Using your example data I do get results: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18771/1)

Comment: Sorry Sam, You are right. I got my columns swap in my table. Thanks

Comment: This seems to be not possible when use `LEFT JOIN ` or `RIGHT JOIN `. Is there a way out?

Comment: If you put columns from your left/right joined table in there it will automatically filter out the NULL values (and therefore behave as a inner join). I updated my answer with something to try for a left join.

Comment: @Manthree Peiris Forgot the notify :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1 T1 INNER JOIN TAB2 T2
ON T1.MemNo = T2.MemID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TAB3 x WHERE x.Col2 =  T2.SVID AND x.Col1 = T1.SID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Above query is giving same syntax error though

Comment: Thanks gzaxx, This also worked after replace `AND ` with `WHERE ` . Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1 T1 INNER JOIN TAB2 T2
ON T1.MemNo = T2.MemID
AND (T1.SID in (SELECT x.Col1 FROM TAB3 x WHERE x.Col2 =  T2.SVID))
```

Comment: @Raveen, Thanks for your response. Above query is giving same syntax error though